# Change color when button is sunken Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, click

How could I make it, so when any button in my program is sunken (so being clicked) that button gets a certain background color (white) for 1 sec.

I was thinking of something like this:

Whenever ButtonClicked = Sunken, ButtonClicked['bg'] = 'white' for 1 sec

But I have lots of buttons, and every button has a different function. So what is an easy to implement program so this happens to all buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create your own custom button class, and add the behavior to that class.

You can use `after` to arrange for the color to be restored after some amount of time.

For example:

```
class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.altcolor = kwargs.pop("altcolor", "pink")
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.twinkle)

    def twinkle(self, event):
        # get the current activebackground...
        bg = self.cget("activebackground")

        # change it ...
        self.configure(activebackground=self.altcolor)

        # and then restore it after a second
        self.after(1000, lambda: self.configure(activebackground=bg))
```

You would use it like you would any other `Button`. It takes one new argument, `altcolor`, which is the extra color you want to use:

```
b1 = CustomButton(root, text="Click me!", altcolor="pink")
b2 = CustomButton(root, text="No, Click me!", altcolor="blue")
```

Comment: Great solution! I'll have to remember the kwargs.pop() method next time

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!